# How do I make a model generate a migration with PK and FK?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to generate two items as primary key and foreign key within sql server, but when I do the migration it doesn't come out as expected. Below are the codes.

```
namespace ContratosMVC.Models
{
    public class AtaRegistroPrecoModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public short Numero { get; set; }
        public short Ano { get; set; }
        public string? Objeto { get; set; }
        public string? Observacao { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }
        public string? Arquivo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
        public ContratoModel? Contrato_ { get; set; }
        public ProcessoModel? Processo_ { get; set; }
        public CorrespondenciaModel? Correspondencia_ { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace ContratosMVC.Models
{
    public class AtaRegistroPrecoFornecedorModel
    {
        [Required, Key, ForeignKey("AtaRegistraPrecoFornecedor_Fornecedor_Id")]
        public AtaRegistroPrecoModel AtaRegistraPrecoFornecedor_Fornecedor_ { get; set; }

        [Required, Key]
        public FornecedorModel Fornecedores_ { get; set; }
    }

    public class AtaRegistroPrecoFornecedorMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AtaRegistroPrecoFornecedorModel>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AtaRegistroPrecoFornecedorModel> builder)
        {
            builder.HasNoKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What the current code generates:

[image: current result]

What I need:

[image: expected result]

I hope you understand why an item is defined with a primary key and a foreign key.

I also hope to solve this problem that I've been holding on to for a long time.

Comment: You are explicitly saying it should not have a key here: `builder.HasNoKey();`. You can define a composite key using the fluent API using something like: `builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Property1, e.Property2 });`, or use the `[Key]` annotation over more than property. [Examples are in the docs for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#composite-keys)

Comment: If I remove 'HasNoKey' from the Configuration, I generate this error:

The entity type 'AtaRegistroPrecoFornecedorModel' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

Comment: Removing `HasNoKey()` is only half the solution. The other half is actually defining the primary key that you want. Please see the second sentence of my first comment for more information about how to define a composite primary key